# android as view layer of spring mvc

Tags: android, model-view-controller, facebook

We are trying to convert one of our J2ee web application to android application.
The idea is that android device will be kind of view layer of spring mvc. Basically the andoird application will invoke the controller on the server and the controller will respond with JSON to the android application. Kind of RESTfull way of doing it.
Question
1)Any suggestions on how to maintain sessions in this situation.
Or if you guys can suggest better way of doing the conversion. Example facebook app of android manages sessions and login/logout and communicate with its servers. I am wondering how to do that.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There was a Google IO session on building RESTfull apps for Android.  It's quite informative.  You can watch it or download the slides here: http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html

Also, the Google IO Session Scheduler app is an *excellent* source reference.  It illustrates a number of Android UI patterns: http://code.google.com/p/iosched/